# How can I deploy two projects with the mvn wildfly:run command

Tags: maven, wildfly-maven-plugin

Can I deploy two projects while using the command maven

```
mvn wildfly:run
```

My two projects are defined in a parent pom.xml file like so

```
...
<modules>
    <module>project-rest-api</module>
    <module>web-frontend</module>
</modules>
...
```

Both projects have the wildfly plugin dependency

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</plugin>
```

And to fire up wildfly and deploy one of the projects I use the following which works fine

```
mvn clean wildfly:run -pl project-rest-api
```

or the other project with

```
mvn clean wildfly:run -pl web-frontend
```

Is there a way to deploy both into the wildfly container?  The following does not work, it only deploys one project

```
mvn clean wildfly:run -pl web-frontend -pl project-rest-api
```

The projects are independent and I don't want them being included as a dependency of the other.

Is it even possible?

Comment: So what about `mvn clean wildfly:run -pl web-frontend,project-rest-api` ?

Comment: That only deploys the first project unfortunately. I think I need to build a script!

Comment: There is currently not a way to do this. The `run` goal blocks and waits for user interaction to stop it from running. What version of WildFly are you targeting?

Comment: Yes I dont think it is possible either,  Wildfly 18.0.1 cheers